# Screen resolution not showing all options on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, display, dell, display-resolution

I recently bought a Dell XPS 9380, I installed Ubuntu 18, everything is perfect, I only have one problem:
I would like to lower the resolution of the laptop screen because I have a large monitor and it ends up being disproportionate, the only option I have is' 1920x1080.

I'd like to know how to enable low level solutions.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268678/best-place-to-automatically-add-mode-in-xrandr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I found the solution.To add new resolutions, you need to use the command `xrandr`.
In my case I would like resolution 1368x768:

```
cvt 1368 768
```

with the output of that command used as a parameter for the new command.

```
xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode eDP-1 "1368x768_60.00"
```

However when restarting the system you will lose these settings, to solve this you must add a script at ubuntu startup.

Create a script called /path/to/.set_monitor.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cvt 1368 768 # xrandr only works in X11 sessions, not Wayland
[ "$XDG_SESSION_TYPE" = x11 ] || exit 0
xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode eDP-1 "1368x768_60.00"
```

and add the following command to startup applications.

```
/bin/bash /path/to/.set_monitor.sh
```