# Not all screen resolutions are showing in ubuntu 18.04 dell xps 13 7390

Tags: display, dell, display-resolution

I bough a dell xps 13 7390 a few days ago. I installed Ubuntu 18.04. Everything is perfect, but the only problem is, the screen resolution is showing just one option using x11. I searched for this problem a lot but could not find a good solution. Although I did find one solution [Screen resolution not showing all options on 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143339/screen-resolution-not-showing-all-options-on-18-04) it did not fix the problem completely. I want to be able to get all the screen resolutions. Is there any way to get all the resolutions? Or is something wrong with the graphics card?[This is what the settings display panel shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XcnL.jpg)

[This is what shows on my 2015 macbook pro running ubuntu 18.04. I want all these resolutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gr6b.png)

When I run `lspci -v -s $(lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1)`

this is the result I get

```
ridwan@ridwan-XPS-13-7390:~$ lspci -v -s $(lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9bca (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0962
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 177
    Memory at 604a000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: What type of graphics do you have? Doesn't the XPS have Nvidia or something? Did you already run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Comment: https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/xps-13-7390-laptop/drivers shows an urgent BIOS update is recommended. Also, https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/04/xps-13-7390-laptop/xps-7390-setup-and-specifications/video shows you could have multiple different Intel CPUs in an XPS 13 7390. Which is in yours? Please also run _lspci -v -s $(lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1)_ then click [edit] and paste the result into your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you.

Comment: This is the result I get when I run 'sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall'

ridwan@ridwan-XPS-13-7390:~$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
[sudo] password for ridwan: 
No drivers found for installation.
ridwan@ridwan-XPS-13-7390:~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.6/0000:02:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v00008086d00002723sv00001A56sd00001653bc02sc80i00
vendor   : Intel Corporation
manual_install: True
driver   : backport-iwlwifi-dkms - distro free

Comment: @K7AAY thanks for the suggestion. I updated my question

Comment: Are you using X11 or Wayland?

Comment: @benrudgers i am using x11

Comment: To my surprise, I also see only one single option on my identical Dell (Ubuntu 19.10). Never noticed this before. Did not consider this as a problem, though, thus far, because it is the native resolution.

Comment: @vanadium its actually alright but I just want the cross icons to be a bit bigger. Any idea if I can use some other programs for that?

Comment: What are the "cross icons"? You will have more luck solving that particular issue by asking it directly in a new question instead of asking it through a way you think might solve it.

Comment: @vanadium i meant the close buttons of every program. yeah I think I might use it the way it is for a few months then lets see if someone finds a solution

Comment: This is where it is a pity that fractional scaling is not possible yet, except for experimental implementation in Wayland. You can give Font Scaling in Gnome Tweaks a try to give the impression of a larger interface.